# Why android run PerformClick as not new Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In java and android world, to run now Thread we execute it like this

```
Thread tr = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        todo();
    }
});
tr.start();
```

so tr is new Thread, but in android api PerformClick implements Runnable interface and is called normally by execute run method

```
private static void handleCallback(Message message) {
    message.callback.run();
}
```

callback is PerformClick

```
private final class PerformClick implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        performClick();
    }
}
```

I am trying understand why for this case it is not new Thread

Thanks

Comment: what is `performClick()` ?

Comment: performClick()  it is method in View class, but for this question body of run method on PerformClick class is not important

Comment: android does all user interface related execution in the main thread, so it doesn't create new threads to run performclick (i'm not sure what's your question, though)